# The FARs "require" the wearing of parachutes for certain types of maneuvers. Is parachute training required?

Tags: faa-regulations, aerobatics, parachute

[FAR 91.307 (c)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1307)  requires that each occupant of an aircraft must wear an approved parachute during the execution of certain types of maneuvers (e.g., more than 60 degrees of bank or
or 30 degrees pitch, etc.).  Is there a legal requirement that those occupants have any specific training in parachute operations or jumping?

Comment: When I got an intro lesson in an aerobatic plane, a parachute was required, but there was no training beyond, "Pull this handle, and hope for the best".

Answer (score 5):

No, no training required. But I tried to train my aerobatic students.

I was trained. Working as a CFI I told my students how to adjust the straps, where the D ring was and how to pull it after exiting the aircraft.  I suggested how to end the ride down with minimal damage to themselves.

As far as when to pull the pins on the door and depart is concerned.  If they hadn't heard me say "Jump" the noise of the air rushing in through the hole caused by my missing door and the lack of my butt in the seat - was a reminder that is was time to leave.